# Enable_broker not working in mysql 5.1 or 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to relate my database with my windows forms application. I want to use the query notifications and for that I have to enable broker previleges. I tried with Mysql 5.1 and 5.6 but both are giving same response.
I used this link for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172133(v=vs.80).aspx
I have tried this query but MySql thows an error.

ALTER DATABASE DBName SET ENABLE_BROKER;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your MySql syntax.

Comment: I hope there is nothing like ENABLE_BROKER in MySQL.

Comment: @AbdulManaf MSDN link says so. I am not sure as it's not working too. Check the link in my question

Answer (score 0):

As stated at the very top of the MSDN article to which you have linked:

> To use query notifications you must:
>
> - Use SQL Server 2005.

[SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sql) is Microsoft's proprietary, commercial RDBMS product.  It is entirely unrelated to [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) (a competing free, open-source, cross-platform RDBMS product now owned by Oracle), whose [`ALTER DATABASE` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-database.html) doesn't have a `SET` clause, let alone an `ENABLE_BROKER` option: hence the syntax error.

Comment: See also [Is there any way to let MySQL server 'push' DB updates to a client program?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1772862)